# How to release an event handler

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Normally, anonymous event handlers can be released as follows:

```
    EventHandler hdl = null;
    hdl += (ss,ee) =>
    {
       //....
       MyObj.Completed -= hdl;            
       hdl = null;
    };

    MyObj.Completed += hdl;            
    MyObj.AsyncCall();
```

My question is: Is `hdl = null;` necessary for the latest version of C#? Also are there any simpler solutions or simpler a syntax for this release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. Simply setting `hdl = null` will not free your handler for garbage collection because MyObj.Completed would still hold the reference to the handler. (But `MyObj.Completed -= hdl` takes care of it in this case, so you should be fine.)
2. You don't have to use `+=` on your assignment to hdl. You should just use simple assignment `=`.
3. If your lambda were, instead, a named method, you could use `MyObj.Completed += MyCallbackName` and `MyObj.Completed -= MyCallbackName`. This doesn't work if you need stuff captured in closure, but I don't see that from your example.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not required. That is basically all tied to a capture-context (compiler-generated class); once the event is unsubscribed, nothing will be keeping the capture-context in scope, so it will be eligible for garbage collection. There is no benefit (but no real harm) wiping the variable `hdl` (actually a field on the capture-context).